# MVC.NET Razor views rendering differently across deployments

Tags: deployment, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have a razor view in an MVC4 project that treats the same input differently in two different environments. I have a script block within an MVC section.

At my live deployment, whenever I create a less than comparison (`if(a < b)`), the `<` will be interpreted as a HTML block, and the section will render in a weird manner. Currently, I have to use `Html.Raw("<")`. At my development machine, I do not have this issue.

I'm sure there's a simple answer to why razor doesn't realize that the `<` is part of my javascript, but right now, I'm only interested in why the behavior would be *different* across delpoyments. I know both setups are running razor v2, since new features like conditional attributes are working in both.

What could be the cause of discrepancies such as this?

Comment: Could you check the file version of System.Web.Razor.dll in both environments and see whether it's 2.0.20715 in both places?  We did release an update to Razor v2 that's included in the MVC 4 installer via Web PI, but isn't in the box in Visual Studio 2012, which might account for the difference in behavior that you're seeing.

Comment: @ClayCompton: Thanks for your input, this seemed promising, but I still haven't quite been able to nail what the real problem is. See my update.

Comment: Something in the GAC that hide one of your local assembly?

Comment: @ClayCompton: After further investigation, it appears it was indeed `System.Web.Razor` that was outdated. I just didn't see that replacing it helped because Temporary ASP.NET Files was obscuring the issue. Please move your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the file version of System.Web.Razor.dll in both environments and see whether it's 2.0.20715 in both places. We did release an update to Razor v2 that's included in the MVC 4 installer via Web PI, but isn't in the box in Visual Studio 2012, which might account for the difference in behavior that you're seeing.